# Python: Most Efficient Way to Split and Analyze String

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I know from other answers that using string.split() over Regex will be a lot faster with short strings. A particular script I am working on requires me to split a string on a delimiter and analyze every split a particular way depending on how many delimiters it is after. For example, my string may look like abd-123-32-few-333-1212 etc....in this case, the delimiter is a '-'. Depending on the situation, I will either need a few or all of the splits (aka, for this example, I may need 32 and 333 and I will need to know that the 32 is after the 2nd dash and the 33 after the 4th).

My current solution is to split on the delimiter and just iterate through that list for the values I need. What I am curious about is if there is a better/faster way to do this. I have already confirmed that Regex is slower and does not meet my needs right out of the box...any other suggestions?

Comment: So what you need is the index of each split part?

Comment: `I may need 32 and 333 and I will need to know that the 32 is after the 2nd dash and the 33 after the 4th).` so you want to check 33 is present in the 4th part?

Comment: I responded to your answer Avinash. In short, I need to find a certain value that is between the delimiter and then I need to know what location it was at. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: you should provide a benchmark code, how fast is it on your machine and how fast do you want it to be, and describe exactly (using words) what does "analyze string" mean in your case

Comment: How many times will you be performing this operation, rounded to the nearest 100,000?

Comment: It will be below 100,000 times (under 100,000 lines to analyze). As far as analyze string goes, I can simplify it to check if the string is full of letters or numbers (never both), and either sum all the digits of the number or see if a certain set of letters are in the string (this is a huge simplification but is fairly representative of my tasks).

Answer (score 3):

This might solve your problem, though since you didn't post your code, I have no idea if it's similar or different or slower or faster:

```
s = 'abd-123-32-few-333-1212'
check = {'32', '333'}
s = s.split('-')
print(dict((y, x) for (x, y) in enumerate(s) if y in check))
```

This prints:

```
{'32': 2, '333': 4}
```

FWIW, you should probably run code like this inside a function rather than in the main body of a script, because local lookups are much faster than global ones.

Comment: do not use the same name for different purposes in the same context e.g., you could use `items = s.split('-')` here.

Comment: `s` may not be the best name for this in a real program, but depending on the context I would probably quite happily write, e.g., `line = line.split()`.  This makes it obvious I am done with the larger string, and am moving on to dealing with the pieces.  Anything else gives me more local variable names to worry about mentally tracking.  SSA is great for compilers, but I am a Bear of Very Little Brain, not a compiler.